# subfolder and html page name is the same and nor working

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I have a webpage, which has got a html page called "blog.html" and a subfolder which is called "blog" and have some other html page inside. I just removed .html with htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Now, when somebody click on the "blog" menu, the following happened:

**You don't have permission to access /blog/.html on this server.**

I wonder how can i fix this, i would like to have a page with working urls like this:

mydomain.com

mydomain.com/blog

mydomain.com/blog/first_post

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule to this:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

And test it in a different browser.